# "Stylesheet could not be loaded" error in Node/Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to load a stylesheet into my page through express, but there is no good reason as far as I can tell as to why it is not working. When I route to the file in a browser, I can see the CSS file, but there seems to be a problem with the app.use. Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

main.js

```
app.use('/css/stylesheet.css', function(req, res) {
    let stylesheet = fs.readFileSync(path.normalize(__dirname+"/views/css/stylesheet.css"), 'utf8');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/css');
    console.log(stylesheet);
    res.send(stylesheet); 
});
```

index.ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css">
```

My file directory:

```
.
|-views
| |-css
| | |-stylesheet.css
| |-index.ejs
|-main.js
```

Comment: try href="css/stylesheet.css" instead of href="/css/stylesheet.css"

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I set the Content-Type as "application/css" instead of "text/css", so the browser wouldn't load the css file.